# How to index a json key array that sometimes only has one element, and is no longer an iterable?

Tags: python, json, iterable

I'm new to json, and I'm having trouble dealing with indexing keys that usually have sub-array but sometimes they don't.

Usually, key2 and key3 contain sub-array:

```
json_obj = json.loads(x)

json_obj["key1"]["key2"][idx]["key3"][idx]["key4"]
```

However, sometimes key2 and/or key3 is no longer an array
executing above code would throw an exception

to retrieve key4:

```
json_obj["key1"]["key2"]["key3"][idx]["key4"]
json_obj["key1"]["key2"][idx]["key3"]["key4"]
json_obj["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]["key4"]
```

Is there an elegant way to retrieve key4 regardless the condition of key2 and key3?

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: To begin with, I'd question sanity of data structure (as presumably serialized into JSON here) that at a given point holds a value or list of values interchangeably -> that does not sound like a reasonable design choice and only dealing with it on the consuming end seems rather suboptimal. But if you really must, you will need to take it apart step (key) by step and at each turn (or at least those with vaguely defined content) check what are you looking at. Simple `try/except` isn't enough as both value (e,g `str`) and `list` can be subscriptable -> so `isinstance` more likely.

Comment: @OndrejK. It's madness indeed, but I have no control over the json source.

Comment: @Unmitigated It's quite large and require API to obtain. I don't see how that's relevant to the question.

Comment: @7E10FC9A It makes it much easier to help when there is sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is transverse the tree, getting the next key if the value is a dictionary or getting an index if the value is a list. Here is a function to do that general behavior:

```
def getKey(data, path, indices):
    el = data
    # keep transversing until we find a primitive value
    while type(el) is dict or type(el) is list:
        if type(el) is list:
            # if el is a list, try using one of the indicies passed
            el = el[indices.pop()]
        else:
            # otherwsie, go along the path specified
            el = el[path.pop(0)]
    return el
```

Note that `list.pop()` removes an element from a list, then returns the element it removed. So, `el[indices.pop()]` removes an index from `indices`, then indexes `el` with that index (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more).

This function takes three parameters, the dictionary to transverse, a list of keys, and a list of indices to use. Indicies will be taken off the beginning of `indices`. In your specific case, you can call it like this:

```
getKey(json_obj, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'], [idx, idx]);
```

Comment: your proposed code indexed key2 with zero and key3 with idx1, what I need is index key2 with idx1 and key3 with idx2. Does the pop method execute before or after el is indexed?

Comment: @7E10FC9A Oops, I think I had a small typo. I meant to say that indicies will be popped off the beginning of the list as needed. My updated example should work. Also, the `.pop()` method executes before `el` has been indexed. Thanks for the good catch!

Comment: @7E10FC9A Does my edited example work for you?

Comment: It works, but you should explain more about the code like add come comment, input argument requirement so other people can understand. Also if ``pop`` method is executed BEFORE ``el`` is indexed, then wouldn't key1 get popped before it's ever used?

Comment: @7E10FC9A I've edited my answer with some comments, an explanation, and a link to the documentation. The `pop` method **is** executed before `el` is indexed, but `pop` returns the element it removed, so `el` is indexed with the value returned (which is the element that was removed).